# php mail is not working on my server

Tags: php

My code is this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sending email using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
   $subject = "This is subject";
   $message = "This is simple text message.";
   mail($to,$subject,$message);

      echo "<br>Message sent successfully...";


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this is very simple but I am not able to solve it my try to help me

Answer (score 0):

Is there a mailserver running on the machine that hosts this page? Most likely not because the code you show should work.

Now there are two options: Install a mailserver or use an additional PHP library to overcome this problem. I'm not gonna post a tutorial on how to install a mailserver so just Google it!

For the PHP library part, u could use PHPMailer. This class holds additional settings for sending the mail via specific servers. First download the needed files from GitHub (on the right side, click "Download zip") https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer . Unzip the package and copy the files to your working directory. The code could be like:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

The easiest way to send mail is to use a gmail account or something. The settings can be found literally everywhere. For example: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail